# Adding a role in discord.py failed with no error

Tags: discord.py

So I got no error but it always sends me back the else message. Can someone say me what I made wrong?

```
import discord

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
ar=discord.Client(intents=intents)

async def on_message(message):
    member = message.author
    if message.content == "/verify":
        role = message.guild.get_role(ROLE_ID)
        await member.add_roles(role)
        await message.author.send("Du bist jetzt auf FlexGames Deescord verifiziert! Viel Spaß und lies dir #infos-regeln durch!")
    else:
        await message.author.send("Die Verifizierung ist fehlgeschlagen! Bitte probiere es erneut!")
```

(If you try this code, don't forget the bot.run('token') and bot=discord.Client() for example). I also gave the bot all permissions it need

EDIT: I updated the code to the new one and activated the intents for the bot, still doesn't work and either sends me back the else message or just gives no error.

Final Edit: I was too stupid to know I got something before that wrong (ar.wait_for) so his solution was right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can only add roles to `discord.Member` instances, when defining the member variable you're getting the ID itself, not the `discord.Member` instance

```py
member = message.author # Without the id attribute
```

2. In `Member.add_roles` you need to pass `discord.Role` instances, not the ID's itself, you can get the instance with `Guild.get_role`

```py
role = message.guild.get_role(role_id)
await member.add_roles(role)
```

Your code fixed:

```py
async def on_message(message):
    member = message.author
    if message.content.startswith("/verify"):
        role = message.guild.get_role(ROLE_ID_HERE)
        await member.add_roles(role)
```

There's another issue, you need to enable `intents.members` and a few more intents, otherwise some attributes can be a `NoneType`

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True # Explicitly enabling members as it's a privileged intent

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
```

Also remember to enable privileged member intents in the [developer portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications), [guide](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html#privileged-intents)

#### Reference:

- [`Member.add_roles`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.add_roles)
- [`Guild.get_role`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.get_role)